# Golang Gorm reverse hasMany relation

Tags: go, go-gorm

We can Easy to get the child of hasMany relation in Golang Gorm with **Preload**.
But how to get reverse of relation.

```
type Owner struct {
    ID         int        `gorm:"column:id" json:"id"`
    Name       string     `gorm:"column:name" json:"name"`
    Projects   []Project  `gorm:"foreignkey:OwnerID" json:"projects"`
}

type Project struct {
    ID          int     `gorm:"column:id" json:"id"`
    Name        string  `gorm:"column:name" json:"name"`
    OwnerID     int     `gorm:"column:owner_id" json:"owner_id"`
    Gallery     []Gallery `gorm:"foreignkey:ProjectID" json:"gallery"`
}

type Gallery struct {
    ID             int    `gorm:"column:id" json:"id"`
    ProjectID      int    `gorm:"column:project_id" json:"project_id"`
    Url            string `gorm:"column:url" json:"url"`
    Title          string `gorm:"column:title" json:"title"`
    Description    string `gorm:"column:description" json:"description"`
}
```

we can populate Gallery inside Project with Preload, like this:

```
db.Preload("Gallery").Find(&project)
```

How to get reverse, we want load project from gallery or owner from project?

the result I want some thing like this, when get project in form of json:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "name": "Name Of Project",
   "owner": {
      "id":1,
      "name": "Owner 1"
   },
   "gallery":[]
}
```

Comment: I am also looking for this. I am coming from NodeJS(express) which has ways to do this. Anyone ?

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit late to the game with this answer, but you can define inverse relationships (belongs to) on the child models by doing this:

```golang
type ParentModel struct {
    Children []Child // This is a 'has many'
}

type Child struct {
    ParentModelID int // These behave as a 'belongs to'
    ParentModel ParentModel // You need both the model and the modelID
}
```

#### Full working example

This uses the models from your question. A note on performance, the preloading in gorm isn't done via joins. It's done via additional SQL queries, the more nesting the more queries. If you have commonly executed preloading, it could be worth writing a raw query and a custom scanner to use an optimised query.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gorm.io/driver/sqlite"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type Owner struct {
    gorm.Model
    Projects []Project
}

type Project struct {
    gorm.Model
    OwnerID int
    Owner   Owner
    Gallery []Gallery
}

type Gallery struct {
    gorm.Model
    ProjectID int
    Project   Project
}

func main() {
    db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("many2many.db"), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to connect database")
    }

    err = db.AutoMigrate(&Owner{}, &Project{}, &Gallery{})
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    ownerOne := Owner{}
    db.Create(&ownerOne)

    projectOne := Project{Owner: ownerOne}
    projectTwo := Project{Owner: ownerOne}
    db.Create(&projectOne)
    db.Create(&projectTwo)

    galleryOne := Gallery{Project: projectOne}
    galleryTwo := Gallery{Project: projectOne}

    galleryThree := Gallery{Project: projectTwo}
    galleryFour := Gallery{Project: projectTwo}

    db.Create(&galleryOne)
    db.Create(&galleryTwo)
    db.Create(&galleryThree)
    db.Create(&galleryFour)

    // Find by project and preload owners
    fetchedProject := Project{}
    db.Preload("Owner").Find(&fetchedProject, projectOne.ID)
    fmt.Println(fetchedProject.Owner)

    // Find by a gallery and preload project and owner
    fetchedGallery := Gallery{}
    db.Preload("Project.Owner").Find(&fetchedGallery, galleryOne.ID)
    fmt.Printf("Gallery.id = %d --> Project.id = %d --> Owner.id = %d\n", fetchedGallery.ID,
        fetchedGallery.Project.ID, fetchedGallery.Project.Owner.ID)
}
```

Comment: Your answer works for me. But I wonder where the constraints for `OnUpdate` and `OnDelete` should be defined. Parent or Child, is there some kind of precedence?